# Implementing busy wait within an async task in Java

Tags: java

I'm building a program in Java 7 and I need to download multiple files from a backend server depending on a different downloaded file value.

I'll explain:

Firstly, my program downloads a file via AsyncTask this file contains the value of files to download. onPost method it calls a different method that downloads these files and insert them into an array list after manipulating them into my app data.

Now, in order to create some kind of handling the ending of these AsyncTasks I've created a different AsyncTask in order to create a busy wait, considering I know how many files are to be downloaded, I check wether the size of the array is equal to the files number on a while loop.

My question is, does this busy wait in the AsyncTask disables the ability of the OS to release the processor it is running on or it's nothing to worry about?

I don't want the busy wait to lock a processor in order to download the files faster, or does it even matter?

Since I assume the async task has its own apoc and goes to sleep if needed I assume there won't be abuse of a processor by this busy wait?

Does the amount of files needed to be downloaded affect processing time? And if yes, does downloading a single file with the data is better than multi threading the download into a few hundred smaller files?

And finally, is it a good practice to write my own busy wait in an AsyncTask?

I'll add some code snippets soon...

Comment: 1. don't do busy wait. 2. find another solution... :) your code knows when all downloads are complete -- the last one adding to the list will see that that list is full, and an event can be triggered there.

Answer (score 0):

*is it a good practice to write my own XYZ* - no, almost never, unless its Free vs proprietary, this is for the new language or platform, you are doing university research or the standard implementation is so crappy that you have realistic chances to take over. In this case, none of the above seems true.

I would suggest to use the standard parts of [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. It has many classes that would be very useful for your project, including the Future class that implements the waiting functionality you need. Futures can be returned by the executor service that is implemented there in even multiple ways.

If you need more control over the process, it is also possible to use the [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). It allows one thread to wait till another completes something, and you can use the time out if you think your download may stall.

To answer clearly and directly, no, there is not a good practice to implement the homegrown framework for the functionality that duplicates that is available for free as part of the standard runtime. With or without busy waiting, do not even matter much.

Comment: I've read about the Future class prior to posting this question and and it does seem helpful, so let me get it straight, all I have to do is instead of doing .execute() is adding the task to the executor service?

Comment: Yes, submit Callable and you will get the Future back.